# Interlocked.Increment at the end of begining of the parallel loop?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

Suppose you have a parallel loop in C# and want to use : Interlocked.Increment

Also, suppose there is a heavy process in your loop. Do you think putting Interlocked.Increment before or after that heavy process might make any difference?

In other words, which of the followings is more preferred?

UPDATE: Suppose our criterion for being better or worse is the overall speed.

Prog1:

```
int iter = 0; 
Parallel.For(...{ 
HeavyProcess()
Interlocked.Increment(iter); 
});
```

Prog2:

```
int iter = 0; 
Parallel.For(...{ 
Interlocked.Increment(iter); 
HeavyProcess()
});
```

Comment: What is the context? What are you trying to count?

Comment: Usually, one will be correct and the other incorrect, for whatever purpose you're keeping count. It won't usually be something you have a choice about.

Comment: @KevinHolditch Sorry about the confusion. Say an iterator variable incremented each step. Updated the question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry I don't get why you are saying the second is  wrong. Would you please clarify? I thought both of these are correct.

Comment: Simply that they do different things. One of them effectively counts "how many of these `HeavyProcess()` operations have started?". The other counts "how many of these `HeavyProcess()` operations have completed?". One of those will usually be the information you want and the other will not. So you choose the one that gives you the information you want and ignore the one that doesn't provide you that information.

Comment: Also, you'll need a `ref` for that to compile.

Answer (score 3):

The "one that is preferred" is simply: the one that is functionally correct. Is it meant to record the number of complete operations (end)? or the number of *started* operations (beginning). Other than that: no difference.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By "which is preferred" I meant in terms of overall speed, which one is better.

Comment: @Daniel neither; they will perform the same. Why do you think it would matter?